# Expected 32 bytes

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, send-transaction, transaction

I am working on helium-Solana migration and writing a script for claiming a reward for all NFTs on the Solana chain. here is my code. But here I am getting this error while running the script.

``` throw new Error(`Expected 32 bytes`);
^

Error: Expected 32 bytes```

Please help how I can resolve this.

```
import {init, lazyDistributorKey} from "@helium/lazy-distributor-sdk";
import { getCurrentRewards } from "@helium/distributor-oracle";
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { formTransaction } from "@helium/distributor-oracle";
import { SOLANA_URL, ANCHOR_WALLET } from "./env";
import { PublicKey, Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

(async() => {

    const mnemonic = "------";
    const seed = Buffer.from(mnemonic, "ascii");
    const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(seed);


    try {
        anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.local(SOLANA_URL));
        const provider = anchor.getProvider()as anchor.AnchorProvider;
        const program = await init(provider);

        const iotMintKeyStr = "iotEVVZLEywoTn1QdwNPddxPWszn3zFhEot3MfL9fns";
        const iotMintKey = new PublicKey(iotMintKeyStr);
        console.log(`iotMint: ${iotMintKey.toBase58()}`)

        const assetIdKeyStr = "TDRy7AjF1vSKoBxqZktwgPDd5q3cB3uVNhZovJvhYRw";
        const assetIdKey = new PublicKey(assetIdKeyStr);
        console.log(`assetId: ${assetIdKey.toBase58()}`)

        const lazyDistributorPKey = lazyDistributorKey(iotMintKey)[0];
        const rewards = await getCurrentRewards(program, lazyDistributorPKey, assetIdKey);
        rewards.map(rewards => {
            console.log(`Oracle ${rewards.oracleKey} stating lifetime rewards of ${rewards.currentRewards}`);
        });

        const tx = await formTransaction({
            program,
            provider,
            rewards,
            hotspot: assetIdKey,
            lazyDistributor: lazyDistributorPKey,
        });

        await provider.sendAndConfirm(tx,[keypair]);

    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(new Error('An error occured: ' + error.message));
        console.error(error.stack);
    }
})();``
```

Comment: Which part of your script is throwing the error? You can probably tell from the stack trace you're logging, if not you might need to use a debugger or add some more logging

Comment: signing transaction is creating error

Answer (score 2):

A `PublicKey` is 32 bytes. Check that your const values don't exceed or fall short of that.

Comment: For which public key you are saying about?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Check that your public key values are valid for Solana. A valid Solana pubkey is a [u8; 32]. In both cases above, the string you're passing into the constructor exceeds that size